# How to combine 2 tables in SQL with 1 common column and no relation in the other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to combine 2 tables with 2 columns each:

- one with Cities | Names
- one with Cities | Streets

One column (`Cities`) in each table contains similar information, but the other columns (`Names` and `Streets`) are independent in each table.

Using the common column, I just want to combine and list all of the other elements in the 2 next column as a single table:

```
Cities | Names | Streets
```

Listing all the `Names` and `Streets` in the original tables with the correct `City` in the first column, with no repeats of `Names` or `Streets` (and adding blanks if there are more `Names` or `Streets` in a certain `City`.

Summary here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQxHJopVBcuUN9RK5fHs7qhVxdry4v3HB6Az3LrRWXJxspV4abTTFS2VQka87GG3s9DHlT6FKUKPWal/pubhtml

I tried different joins, but then I get all of the combinations between the `Names` and `Streets`, which is not what I want.

This does not work:

```
select *  
from city, street 
where city.city = street.city
order by city.name asc, street.name asc;
```

Please see the GoogleSheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQxHJopVBcuUN9RK5fHs7qhVxdry4v3HB6Az3LrRWXJxspV4abTTFS2VQka87GG3s9DHlT6FKUKPWal/pubhtml

Adding code to create the tables, in case someone want to try and play with this:

```
CREATE TABLE names  
(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE streets 
(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    street VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'paris', 'nameP1');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'paris', 'nameP2');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'paris', 'nameP3');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (4, 'paris', 'nameP4');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (5, 'paris', 'nameP5');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (6, 'tokyo', 'nameT1');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (7, 'tokyo', 'nameT2');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (8, 'tokyo', 'nameT3');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (9, 'tokyo', 'nameT4');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (10, 'tokyo', 'nameT5');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (11, 'tokyo', 'nameT6');

INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (1, 'paris', 'streetP1');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (2, 'paris', 'streetP2');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (3, 'paris', 'streetP3');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (4, 'tokyo', 'streetT1');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (5, 'tokyo', 'streetT2');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (6, 'tokyo', 'streetT3');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (7, 'tokyo', 'streetT4');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (8, 'tokyo', 'streetT5');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (9, 'tokyo', 'streetT6');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (10, 'tokyo', 'streetT7');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (11, 'tokyo', 'streetT8');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (12, 'tokyo', 'streetT9');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (13, 'tokyo', 'streetT10');
```

Adding here my tables and expected results:

Table **names**:

```
+---—+-------+--------+
| id |  City |  Names | 
+---—+-------+--------+
|  1 | paris | nameP1 |
|  2 | paris | nameP2 |
|  3 | paris | nameP3 |
|  4 | paris | nameP4 |
|  5 | paris | nameP5 |
|  6 | tokyo | nameT1 |
|  7 | tokyo | nameT2 |
|  8 | tokyo | nameT3 |
|  9 | tokyo | nameT4 |
| 10 | tokyo | nameT5 |
| 11 | tokyo | nameT6 |
+---—+-------+--------+
```

Table **streets**:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id |  City |   Streets | 
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 | paris |  streetP1 |
|  2 | paris |  streetP2 |
|  3 | paris |  streetP3 |
|  4 | tokyo |  streetT1 |
|  5 | tokyo |  streetT2 |
|  6 | tokyo |  streetT3 |
|  7 | tokyo |  streetT4 |
|  8 | tokyo |  streetT5 |
|  9 | tokyo |  streetT6 |
| 10 | tokyo |  streetT7 |
| 11 | tokyo |  streetT8 |
| 12 | tokyo |  streetT9 |
| 13 | tokyo | streetT10 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

Expected results:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
| City  | Names   | Streets   |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| paris |  nameP1 |  streetP1 |
| paris |  nameP2 |  streetP2 |
| paris |  nameP3 |  streetP3 |
| paris |  nameP4 |           |
| paris |  nameP5 |           |
| tokyo |  nameT1 |  streetT1 |
| tokyo |  nameT2 |  streetT2 |
| tokyo |  nameT3 |  streetT3 |
| tokyo |  nameT4 |  streetT4 |
| tokyo |  nameT5 |  streetT5 |
| tokyo |  nameT6 |  streetT6 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT7 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT8 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT9 |
| tokyo |         | streetT10 |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

Please note:

- Table 'names' lists 5 names in paris, 6 names in tokyo
- Table 'streets' lists 3 streets in paris, 10 streets in tokyo
- Results should list the 2 cities in column 1, with the 5 names and 3 streets in paris in the next 2 columns next to paris, and then the 6 names and 10 streets in tokyo next to the tokyo
- there is not relation between the names and streets, except they are in the same city
- there are more names than streets in Paris, more streets than names in Tokyo, so some values are left blank to accommodate this

Following up on Gordon's answer below: almost there, but not 100%, as I want to keep the city's row together.
It I have more streets in partis, that is not quite that - see:

If I start with:

CREATE TABLE names ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE streets ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
street VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'paris', 'nameP1');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'paris', 'nameP2');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'paris', 'nameP3');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (4, 'paris', 'nameP4');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (5, 'paris', 'nameP5');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (6, 'tokyo', 'nameT1');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (7, 'tokyo', 'nameT2');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (8, 'tokyo', 'nameT3');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (9, 'tokyo', 'nameT4');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (10, 'tokyo', 'nameT5');
INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `city`, `name`) VALUES (11, 'tokyo', 'nameT6');

INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (1, 'paris', 'streetP1');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (2, 'paris', 'streetP2');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (3, 'paris', 'streetP3');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (3, 'paris', 'streetP4’);
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (3, 'paris', 'streetP5’);
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (3, 'paris', 'streetP6’);
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (3, 'paris', 'streetP7’);
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (4, 'tokyo', 'streetT1');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (5, 'tokyo', 'streetT2');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (6, 'tokyo', 'streetT3');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (7, 'tokyo', 'streetT4');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (8, 'tokyo', 'streetT5');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (9, 'tokyo', 'streetT6');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (10, 'tokyo', 'streetT7');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (11, 'tokyo', 'streetT8');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (12, 'tokyo', 'streetT9');
INSERT INTO `streets` (`id`, `city`, `street`) VALUES (13, 'tokyo', 'streetT10');

I am creating these 2 tables:

TABLE names
+—--—+——-——-—+—-—-————+
| id |  City |  Names | 
+———+————-—-—+———-————+
|  1 | paris | nameP1 |
|  2 | paris | nameP2 |
|  3 | paris | nameP3 |
|  4 | paris | nameP4 |
|  5 | paris | nameP5 |
|  6 | tokyo | nameT1 |
|  7 | tokyo | nameT2 |
|  8 | tokyo | nameT3 |
|  9 | tokyo | nameT4 |
| 10 | tokyo | nameT5 |
| 11 | tokyo | nameT6 |
+———+————-—-—+———-————+

TABLE streets
+——-—+——-——-—+—————-—-———+
| id |  City |   Streets | 
+——-—+—————-—+—————-—————+
|  1 | paris |  streetP1 |
|  2 | paris |  streetP2 |
|  3 | paris |  streetP3 |
|  4 | paris |  streetP4 |
|  5 | paris |  streetP5 |
|  6 | paris |  streetP6 |
|  7 | paris |  streetP7 |
|  8 | tokyo |  streetT1 |
|  9 | tokyo |  streetT2 |
| 10 | tokyo |  streetT3 |
| 11 | tokyo |  streetT4 |
| 12 | tokyo |  streetT5 |
| 13 | tokyo |  streetT6 |
| 14 | tokyo |  streetT7 |
| 15 | tokyo |  streetT8 |
| 16 | tokyo |  streetT9 |
| 17 | tokyo | streetT10 |
+———+————-—-—+———-———-———+

I want to get:

+——-——-—+—————-———+———-——-——-—+
|  City |   Names |   Streets |
+—————-—+—————-———+————-————-—+
| paris |  nameP1 |  streetP1 |
| paris |  nameP2 |  streetP2 |
| paris |  nameP3 |  streetP3 |
| paris |  nameP4 |  streetP4 |
| paris |  nameP5 |  streetP5 |
| paris |         |  streetP6 |
| paris |         |  streetP7 |
| tokyo |  nameT1 |  streetT1 |
| tokyo |  nameT2 |  streetT2 |
| tokyo |  nameT3 |  streetT3 |
| tokyo |  nameT4 |  streetT4 |
| tokyo |  nameT5 |  streetT5 |
| tokyo |  nameT6 |  streetT6 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT7 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT8 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT9 |
| tokyo |         | streetT10 |
+——-——-—+—————-———+———-——-——-—+

But with Gordon's initial response below, i am getting:

+——-——-—+—————-———+———-——-——-—+
|  City |   Names |   Streets |
+—————-—+—————-———+————-————-—+
| paris |  nameP1 |  streetP1 |
| paris |  nameP2 |  streetP2 |
| paris |  nameP3 |  streetP3 |
| paris |  nameP4 |  streetP4 |
| paris |  nameP5 |  streetP5 |
| tokyo |  nameT1 |  streetT1 |
| tokyo |  nameT2 | streetT10 |
| tokyo |  nameT3 |  streetT2 |
| tokyo |  nameT4 |  streetT3 |
| tokyo |  nameT5 |  streetT4 |
| tokyo |  nameT6 |  streetT5 |
| paris |         |  streetP6 |
| paris |         |  streetP7 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT6 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT7 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT8 |
| tokyo |         |  streetT9 |
+——-——-—+—————-———+———-——-——-—+

Any idea? Seems just an ordering issus somewhere, but I can't figure it out.... Thanks!!

Comment: Can yo share the table structure of city and street table along with some sample data?

Comment: Sure - I've just added this above - thanks

Comment: Please show the results you want.

Comment: Please do not post in links especially requiring sign-in as they may break for future readers . Include all content in body of post.

Comment: Got it - I've try to put the tables and expected results inline above now, but am struggling with the formatting .. sorry for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want "vertical" lists.  This is not really how SQL works, but you can do it, using `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select city, max(name) as name, max(street) as street
from ((select city, name, null as street,
              row_number() over (partition by city order by name) as seqnum
       from names
      ) union all
      (select city, null, street,
              row_number() over (partition by city order by street) as seqnum
       from streets
      )
     ) sn
group by city, seqnum
order by city, seqnum;
```

Comment: OMG - exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you so much! I don't even know how you understood my question, but you got it all right! This is a huge help, thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW: just a small detail, but the second 'from names' above should read 'from streets' - mentioning just in case someone else is trying this

Comment: Hi Gordon, another quick question on this problem: I notices that if I have more streets in paris than tokyo, then your query do not keep all of the paris' rows together - I do not quite understand why, but once the paris's names are filled with the same number of paris's streets, than it switches to the tokyo names and streets, and comes back to paris with the start of 'null' names ... maybe this is the way 'max works in conjunction with order by? Any idea?  See my last edits above...

Comment: @DominiqueBouchon . . . I think you might just need to order the results.

Comment: Right on, I was so focused on understanding your query that I just forgot the order by ...  thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm wrong but aren't you only look for inner join query?

```
select city.cities, city.names, street.streets from city inner join street on city.cities=street.cities
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - not quite, inner join will actually create all combinations of Names and Streets for their Common Cities. In my case, I want Names and Streets to appear only once, lines up with tier city, at the top of the Names and StreetS column for the block corresponding to their city...

Comment: Please **show** not **tell** your output. Natural languages like English can be imprecise whereas data illustrates better.